# Python Tuple Issue

Tags: python, tuples

I'm learning Python Tuple, and feeling a bit overwhelmed. I'm working with a tuple about 20 times the size of what I've put together below.

```
{u'0UsShTrY': {u'a': {u'n': u'Backups'}, u'h': u'0UsShTrY', u'k': (16147314, 17885416, 1049370661, 902515467), u'ts': 13734967, u'p': u'5RtyGQwS', u'u': u'xpz_tb-YDUg', u't': 1, 'key': (16147314, 17885516, 10490661, 9015467)}, 
u'oMV32IgB': {u'a': {'n': 'Rubbish Bin'}, u'h': u'oMV32IgB', u'k': u'', u'ts': 13734735, u'p': u'', u'u': u'xpz_tb-YDUg', u't': 4}, 
u'AclTQTAa': {u'a': {u'n': u'Test3'}, u'h': u'AclTQTAa', u'k': (4031580, 13207606, 20877418,89356117), u'ts': 1373476935, u'p': u'4FlnwBTb', u'u': u'xpz_tb-YDUg', u't': 1, 'key': (4032580, 13208406, 20627418, 4893117)}, 
u'kEk0RbKR': {u'a': {u'n': u'Abandon All Ships - 5 - Stange Love.mp3'}, u'h': u'kEk0RbKR', u'k': (4714448, 440504, 14565743L, 7910538L), u'ts': 13737027, 'iv': (4284718, 20627111, 0, 0), u'p': u'wQkyFS6S', u's': 1731926, 'meta_mac': (3010404L, 2624700L), u'u': u'xpz_tb-YDUg', u't': 0, 'key': (94654, 201535, 385311L, 301074L, 42818, 204311, 3010404L, 269100L)}}
```

Now, my issue is, I'm trying to access the data of located in where you see *"Test3"* or *"Abandon All Ships - 5 - Stange Love.mp3"*, as well as for example where you see *"u'p': u'5RtyGQwS',"* on the first line. How would I go about accessing these without predefining any of the information that comes up in the tuple?

Any help is apprecieated. Thanks.

Comment: That's a dictionary, not a tuple. There are tuples in the dictionary, like `(16147314, 17885416, 1049370661, 902515467)`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Is your syntax incorrect, or did you mean to say dict instead of tuple? In Python, {} defines dictionaries (associative arrays), and () defines tuples (immutable lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract some of the data with comprehensions, like this:

```
[d[k]['a']['n'] for k in d]
# => [u'Backups', 'Rubbish Bin', u'Test3', u'Abandon All Ships - 5 - Stange Love.mp3']
```

(assuming you have your dict (and it's a dict, as Dan and David say, not a tuple) in `d`).

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to have showed is not in fact a tuple but a dictionary which is made of of key/value pairs, and some of those values are themselves dictionaries with key/value pairs some of which contain tuples.

If this Dict is called MusicDict for example you would access the information you need like this:

To access the first line information:

```
MusicDict['0UsShTrY']['p']
```

This will return '5RtyGQwS'

To access Access all ships:

```
MusicDict['kEk0RbKR'][['a']['n']
```

This will return "Abandon All Ships"

I'm not sure this is the most helpful structure for  your data though, it looks a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored in nested [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), not [tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). In a dictionary, you can access a value directly using its key (e.g. d['key']). In the case of tuples, you can only access an element by its index (e.g. t[2] would access the 3rd element in tuple t).

To access the value "Test3" from your data, you can do it by

```
data['AclTQTAa']['a']['n']
```